# Meta Refresh with a frame target

Tags: php, meta-tags, frames

I have a very basic frame layout: index.html

```
<frameset rows="80,*" frameborder="1" border="5" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="topNav" src="top_nav.html">
    <frameset cols="220,*" frameborder="1" border="5" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="menu" src="menu_1.php" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
    <frame name="content" src="content.php" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize> 
</frameset>
</frameset>
```

[image]

And a simple login script which checks if the username and password match the database and so on

Now what i want it to do is if the information is correct, is to auto redirect the menu bar, but all i can do is redirect the content section

```
// check to see if they match!
  if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassoword)
  {
      $_SESSION['username']=$username;
      echo '<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="2 ; url=servers.php" target="menu">';
  }
  else 
      echo "<center>Incorrect Information!</center>" ;
```

Now i can easily do it if i get the user to click on an `<a href>` tag

E.G. `<a href="servers.php" target="menu">click me</a>`

So i thought i could simply put the `target="menu"` in my `meta` tags, but all it does is redirect the content page.

So my question is, am i doing something wrong, or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Its been forever since i've ever seen a frameset used on a website...or meta refreshes for that matter. If your already using PHP, why not just include those sections into your display - instead of making frames... Then you can just do a header('Location: something') after successful login.

If you want to stick with frames, i'd sugest using JavaScript to force the reload over a meta tag. document.getElementById('menu').location = "something", maybe?

Comment: hello applehat, if i'm honest and i'm not a big fan of frames, but i've wanted to give it ago now for a while, so i made a little project for my self and have learned many things on the way. But in future i will make it using CSS as it seems more reliable. and thank you for your answer, it also worked :)

Comment: No problem! Yeah. Framesets and Meta Refreshes are really old tech in the web world. About the only "acceptable" frames anymore are iFrames... and even they should be used sparingly. JavaScript lets you do everything a lot cleaner now =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can't do it with headers. You could output regular javascript along your content. Something  like this:

```
<script>
    parent.menu.location.href = "/some-url";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give you frame (menu) an id: Then change the code like this:

Change

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="2 ; url=servers.php" target="menu">';
```

To

```
echo '<script>var iframe = document.getElementById("youriframe");iframe.src="servers.php";</script>';
```